# Vertically Centering anchor tag To Right Floating Element

Tags: html, css

I have been looking for a way to center an anchor tag vertically according to a span tag, which are both encased within div tag.

**My HTML**

```
<div id="project_list">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="/projects/example/">Example Project</a>
    <span class="show_details">Show Details</span>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS**

```
div#project_list {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

div#project_list div.title {
  background: grey;
  padding   : 10px;
}

div#project_list div.title a {
  font-size: 1.231rem;
}

div#project_list span.show_details {
  background: orange;
  float     : right;
  padding   : 13px 5px;
}
```

I have also create a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OpenNOX/GxqTh/1/), so you may see what I am speaking about.

Thank you to everyone in advance as I have been racking my brain on how to do this for a couple days now.

Comment: One simple way would be a `line-height` for the `a` element: http://jsfiddle.net/GxqTh/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the line height to match the button height:

`a { line-height:46px; }`

**Note:** I just used `a` but you will probably want to add a class so the style doesn't get applied to all anchor tags.

http://jsfiddle.net/GxqTh/2/

Answer (score 0):

@OpenNoxdiv- try adding padding to your a tag; 20px seemed to center nicely for me. - see below

```
#project_list div.title a {
```

padding-top:20px;
}